# Where's my Badge?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

I just finished doing 50 tag wiki edits and I expected to get the "Research Assistant" Badge, but its not there.

I thought maybe it takes a while, but it already been a while. So what's up or am I not patient enough?

[image]

And this does say 100%, so am I missing something besides my badge.

Comment: This is just a guess, but it could be that the system only automatically awards badges like this at a certain time each day. For [tag badges](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze), it's about 3:00 UTC - in about 3 1/2 hours. I don't know if this is the case for this badge, but it might be. Also, unless I'm mistaken, the system for tag badges is a little on the fritz, as multiple users should be getting these, but have not, even though they qualified over 24 hours ago. If there's something wrong there, the same could be true here. Oh, and congrats!

Comment: You got the badge 8 minutes ago, so I guess this whole thing is moot.

Comment: How long did you wait?  Some badge scripts only run daily.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I first checked ~36 hours ago. I vaguely recall seeing somewhere on the mother Meta that errors sometimes happen with this, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the badges getting awarded run at different times to keep from bogging down the system.  Usually within 24 hours most badges that you should receive show up.  Some badges like the Unsung Hero has an extra '10 days' appended to the end, though the badge wiki doesn't say it.  So 10 days after meeting the criteria if you still meet it you get that badge.

Others are almost immediately, so that might throw your expectations off a little bit.

Comment: I wonder if we have anyone on pace to get that one.

Comment: @HDE226868 :) I doubt it!  I did just get it last weekend on Stack Overflow and it showed up a couple days later than I expected, my 10 days was up last Friday and it finally showed up on Sunday.

Comment: Well, thanks but I thought that the badge would come immediately like they usually do. 1+

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock  ya many show up within minutes, but some really take a bit longer.

Answer (score 5):

Your *Research Assistant* badge was **awarded,** ironically enough, ten minutes after you posted your question.

You posted your question at 23:10 UTC, and [the badge was awarded at 23:20 UTC](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant?userid=56).

As Monica pointed out in a comment, **badges may not be awarded instantly.** In general, I would recommend waiting 48 hours before surmising that something is amiss.

Well done!